# Any way to make closure which takes a destructured array?

Tags: parameters, rust, pattern-matching, closures

I was doing [this code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189358/is-it-double-speak), and figured out this solution to the problem:

```
fn main() {
    let f = |s:&[u8]|s.chunks(2).all(|n|n[0]==n[1]);
    println!("{}", f(b"TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!"));
}
```

This solution works, but I thought the `n[0]==n[1]` didn't look too elegant and tried something like:

```
fn main() {
    let f = |s:&[u8]|s.chunks(2).all(|[a,b]|a==b);
    println!("{}", f(b"TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!"));
}
```

But this fails with the error:

> ```
> error[E0005]: refutable pattern in function argument: `&[]` not covered
>  --> src/main.rs:2:39
>   |
> 2 |     let f = |s:&[u8]|s.chunks(2).all(|[a,b]|a==b);
>   |                                       ^^^^^ pattern `&[]` not covered
> ```

Is there any way to make the above work **by just changing the closure parameters** (everything else should be kept as is):

```
fn main() {
    let f = |s:&[u8]|s.chunks(2).all(|/* anything here */|a==b);
    println!("{}", f(b"TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Function arguments are patterns, and those patterns must always be irrefutable.

---

Using `itertools`, you could do this:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let f = |s:&[u8]|s.iter().tuples().all(|(a,b)|a==b);
    println!("{}", f(b"TThhiiss  iiss  ddoouubbllee  ssppeeaakk!!"));
}
```

This can work because `tuples` will infer that it needs exactly 2 elements. If there are an odd number of elements, the last one will be ignored.